# WPF binding mvvm StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, stackpanel

I am beginner in wpf, and I have a problem with stackpanel binding.
I have to dynamically generate labels, and add it to stackpanel. 
I had following code in .cs file:

```
    public DataImport()
    {
        labels.Add(new StringObject { Value = "tes" });
        labels.Add(new StringObject { Value = "tes2" });
        labels.Add(new StringObject { Value = "tes3" });
    }
    private ObservableCollection<StringObject> labels = new ObservableCollection<StringObject>();

    public ObservableCollection<StringObject> Labels
    {
        get { return labels; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == labels) return;
            labels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Labels");
        }
    }
    public class StringObject
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Next in xaml I have:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Labels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="237" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The real problem is that in xaml window I see only the first element from the labels object.
Can u tell me what i did wrong ?

PS: my class DataImport of course inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: It looks like you're creating one StackPanel per item in your ItemsControl. Is there a reason you're not just binding a ListBox to your Labels collection?

Comment: Yes, I can't use ListBox becouse this will be mapping from file fields to database files. This labels are only for user information what he will map.

Comment: @AndrewS I change my xaml and it works. You was right ;) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemTemplate is per item. So just specify a label.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Labels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```